# Loading Hangfire configuration from appsettings.json in ASP.NET CORE web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, connection-string, hangfire

I'm trying to use Hangfire with SQL Server, reading the connection string from the ***appsettings.json*** file. It doesn't work. Only when I provide the connection string to the ***UseSqlServerStorage*** method, does it work.

Here's **appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HangfireDemo": "Data Source=VSQL64;Initial Catalog=HangfireDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

And here the line that configures Hangfire in **Startup.ConfigureServices**:

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Data Source=VSQL64;Initial Catalog=HangfireDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"));
```

If I write "HangfireDemo" in the **UseSqlServerStorage** method, it doesn't work. Only the full connection string in this method works.
How can I provide just the connection string name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should be able to do it something like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);


    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

}


public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => 
    configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireDemo"))
    );  

}
```